# Use of Mocking in unit testing for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a basic webapp and I'm using ASP.NET MVC, MOno and C# and MySQL for my database. I want to create a unit testing and use mocking. But I don't know how to setup or create a mock in unit testing. And what mocking framework should I use?

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163904.aspx

http://quickduck.com/blog/2008/02/18/unit-testing-mocking-and-dependency-injection/

There are several mocking frameworks. This question can help you pick one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-mocking-framework-to-use